# setting cookie from one subdomain to another in php

Tags: php

I have a website where the site-root is a.xyz.net and inside this there is another directory b.xyz.net ad inside this I have another directory c.xyz.net . I want to set cookie in c.xyz.net from b.xyz.net . How to achieve it?

I have a file in b.xyz.net that sends a curl request  to a file in c.xyz.net for setting cookie using

```
setCookie("myCookie" , "oreo" , time()+3600 , "/","c.xyz.net");
```

but cookie is not set

Comment: Just set the cookie to xyz.net...should work even for other subs

Comment: cookie should only be for c.xyz.net

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php

Comment: Any reason why not to set it for all other subdomains? It won't break anything if you just set it for all domains...since well you'll only call it only where you need it